# cannot access net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager, class file for net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager not found

Tags: maven, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache, terracotta

I have been implementing some caching in my project using `EhCache`. I have added following dependencies to my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ehcache/ehcache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note the third dependency which is for `EhCache`. In all the tutorials I found online, the group id is different. The reason for me to change the group id was it had been moved to `org.ehcache`.

I have the following ehcache.xml file in my classpath.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <cache name="cardTypes"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300"
           timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Following is my configuration file.

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        factory.setShared(true);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Now, I am getting an error in following line.

```
return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
```

That is:

In Eclipse:-

> The type net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class files

In JIdea:

> ```
> Error:(21, 71) java: cannot access net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
>   class file for net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager not found
> ```

I have not added any net.sf.ehcache stuff into my project. As I mentioned before, the `ehcache` has been moved to `org.ehcache`.

Why I am getting this error? It is related to `net.sf.ehcache` which is not a part of the dependencies I have added.

Should I code the second bean in a different way since the artifact has been moved? or how can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ehcache 2 is in the `net.sf.ehcache` package. Most tutorial are about it since it had a long and useful life. Ehcache 3, the version you configured, is quite new (but of course better) and in the `org.ehcache` package.

The package moved because having its own domain was nicer but also because the new version is quite different and be able to cohabit with the old version can be necessary (because of some framework using it).

Your error comes from the fact that `EhCacheCacheManager` is using Ehcache 2. Ehcache 3 doesn't need it because it is JCache compliant. So you can use `JCacheCacheManager` instead.

So, right now, you have the Spring wiring and an `ehcache.xml` for Ehcache 2. And a dependency to Ehcache 3. You should align them to fix your problem.

To use Ehcache 3, the easiest is to add this in your `application.properties`

```
spring.cache.jcache.config=ehcache.xml
```

And this:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much. After trying several things, the solution I came up with was using the old Ehcache 2. That solved the issue. However, this is also a solution. I am accepting this. :)

Comment: thanks ;-) As I said, moving the dependency to ehcache 2 also works of course :-)

Comment: Thanks! I found an example code with ehcache 2 that works: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-ehcache-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency in pom file:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
     <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId> 
     <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```